# Parametrization of a paraboloid

Tags: parametrization

I need to parameterize the curve in the first octant to apply Stokes' theorem...

$$Z=9-x^2-y^2$$

Using the paramaters...

$$C_1 = (3\cos \theta,3\sin \theta,0); 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$$

$$C_2 = (x,0,9-x^2); 0 \leq x \leq 3$$

$$C_3 = (0,y,9+y^2); -3 \leq y \leq 0$$

Can someone help me by telling me if it's right or wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not $(u,v) \mapsto (u,v,9-u^2-v^2)$ for $u \geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$?

Comment: Hi!  sorry for not advising but i only need one parameter to apply stokes theorem

Comment: So, you are parametrizing the boundary of the surface instead?

Comment: exactly the boundary

Comment: Your paraboloid is like a sugar loaf that you cut in 4 pieces. Your 2 first parameterizations are good. Not the third one which should be $(0,y,9-y^2)$

Comment: The above comment is right, your third parameterization should be $y \mapsto (0,y,9-y^2)$ for $0 \leq y \leq 3$. Also, you can check [this](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/nvnps3tt) to convince yourself. Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks guys! but the boundary shouldn't be in counterclockwise? (3,0,0) > (0,3,0) > (0,0,9) and again (3,0,0)? I think it could be (0,−y,9−y^2) −3≤y≤0

Comment: You are right!!

Comment: Thanks azi!!!!!